# Cisco cross-vlan routing

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, vlan, layer3

I have the following config snippets on a layer 3 switch:

```
ip routing
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/22
 switchport access vlan 51
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23
 switchport access vlan 15
 switchport mode access
!
interface Vlan15
 ip address 192.168.15.240 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan51
 ip address 192.168.51.1 255.255.255.0
!
```

I have no access lists.

```
Computer A is 192.168.51.50 on Vlan 51.

Computer B is 192.168.15.200 on Vlan 15.
```

G1/0/23 actually plugs into a dumb switch, and Vlan15 is a large unmanaged network on the .15 range.

Computer A can ping `192.168.15.240`, however cannot ping computer B. My Layer 3 switch can ping 192.168.15.240, however.

Computer B does not have `192.168.15.240` as gateway. However, I don't know if this matters.

Why is routing not working between computer A and B? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a host to communicate with any other host not on its network, it needs to have a proper gateway configuration. A host will mask both the destination and its own source addresses with its network mask to determine if the destination address is on a different network. If the destination address is on a different network, then the traffic gets sent to its configured gateway, and it is up to the gateway to send the traffic to the other network.

If either of your hosts do not have their gateways set to their respective gateway addresses (the IP addresses on the SVI for their respective VLANs), then you cannot have two-way communication between the two hosts, because traffic destined for the other network will never be sent to the gateway for routing to the other network.

> Why is routing not working between computer A and B?

Routing seems to be working from Computer A to Computer B, but not the other way around. Ping is bidirectional, and Computer B is getting the ping request from Computer A, but Computer B is unable to reply because it has no route to Computer A.

Answer (score 3):

Computer B needs to have a default gateway if it needs to communicate with endpoints on a different subnet. Typically, endpoints get their default gateway from a DHCP server automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Computer A requires a mask of 255.255.255.0 and a default gayeway of 192.168.51.1.

Computer B requires a mask of 255.255.255.0 and a default gateway of 192.168.15.240.

Answer (score -2):

Check connectivity post enabling " IP routing " command in layer3 switch .

This command ensures inter-Vlan routing between different Vlans . Try this connectivity post enabling  "IP routing "

Comment: "Computer A can ping 192.168.15.240", so very obviously routing is already turned on.

Comment: The very first line of the configuration of the device posted by the op is... ..."ip routing".